# Online logarithm drawing

Tags: functions, logarithms

I am looking for a site that will give me the output of my logarithms.

What I want to do, is I want to input, in example `log(2)`, and I want it to draw an output for `from log(2) 2 to log(2) 100000`

I found this site: `http://www.numberempire.com/graphingcalculator.php`, it draws what I want if I input `log(x)`, but I need similar input but for fixed logarithm (in example log(2)).

Comment: have you ever used [this site](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)?

Comment: Might [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+log_2%28x%29+x+from+2+to+100000) be what you're looking for? Also, $\log_2 (x) =  \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}$ is a nice cheat.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at wolfram, but I think it isn't drawing what I want because I don't know how to input my function correctly. If I input `log(2)`, it gives me function where all the values are the same, so currently I am inputting values manyally, like `log(2) 10`, but it isn't drawing anything, this only gives me a flat number, like calculator does.

Comment: @ojek Look at my link for how to do it.

Comment: @Arthur: Yeah, that helped, thanks!

Comment: These days, even typing "log(x)/log(2) from 1 to 10000" in google will generate a plot automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your notation is not the usual notation. A person will usually parse $\log(2)$ as either $\log_{10}(2)$ or $\ln(2)=\log_e(2)$ depending on context, which in both cases is just a real number. However, you want to plot a *function* and, from what I can gather, you want to plot the function $\log_2(x)$ for $2\leq x\leq 100000$. To input this in to a program or web interface, you'll either have to write log_2(x) or log(x)/log(2) (these are the same expression by the properties of logarithms).

In Wolfram Alpha, you get [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+log_2%28x%29++from+x%3D2+to+x%3D100000) or [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+log%28x%29%2Flog%282%29++from+x%3D2+to+x%3D100000) which are the same output.